# Google Map not loading with separate files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't see the google map on my monitor, but when I put all the code in a single html file and use script tags it works.

Index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBIpWlWVDAqVEyW20SX6MfThL-iz9IWeQA&callback=initMap"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Script.js file is:

```
function initMap() {

    var map;
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
            {
              center: {  lat: -34.397, 
                         lng: 150.644
                      },
              zoom: 8
            }
            );
          }
```

style.css file is:

```
* element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked the console log for any errors?

Comment: yes no errors in the console log

Comment: Did you inspect in your browser if the map div is filled with content?

Answer (score 0):

```
#map { width:100%; height:200px;}
```

or to fill whole window:

```
#map { width:100%; min-height:100%;}
```

if it's first child with min-height property. PS. You can also try to add overflow:hidden; for second example.

Answer (score 0):

I consolidated your HTML and it works fine. For some reason, your callback function is not working when in a separate file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  <script>
  function initMap() {
    var map;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
    {
      center: {  lat: -34.397,  lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    }
    );
   }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBIpWlWVDAqVEyW20SX6MfThL-iz9IWeQA&callback=initMap"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems callback function is not working when called in a separate file. Though no errors reported.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation : [Google Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en), just put your JavaScript (script.js) after your map.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBIpWlWVDAqVEyW20SX6MfThL-iz9IWeQA&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

**Edit** : Don't forget "**async defer**" at the end of the second script.

Comment: still not working even after implemnting the above changes

Comment: Ok, it's very strange, i copy past your code in my "www" folder and it works directly. Paths to "style.css" and "script.js" are correct? Maybe JavaScript is disable on your browser...

Answer (score -1):

When you execute script.js it tries to find the div with the id="map". But it's not initialized yet .So, you need to do two things:

1. Include the script.js file **after** your `<div id="map"></div>`
2. Call `initMap()` **after the page has loaded**. E.g. like this (at the end) `<script>initMap()</script>`